# GUID vs md5 hash for persistent cookie

Tags: security, authentication, cookies, guid

I am researching how to implement a persistent "remember me" type cookie for a site. I was just wondering is using a GUID for a security token as secure an an md5 hash of username and password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A GUID is more "secure", because there's no possibility of information disclosure in a random identifier. Otherwise, were the username to be known, the password could be extracted using a per-username *rainbow table* or a concerted attack since you did not add salt before hashing. NB: MD5 is a rather weak hash at this point.

Long story short, if you don't need to store private information in cookies for **really really** good reasons, don't. Use a random token instead.

Comment: So it would be good practice to use a GUID for a security token in persistent cookies?

Comment: @chobo Yes, that's fine. So long as you don't give *access* to anything based solely on the cookie... Obviously you can't set a stay-logged-in-forever cookie and maintain security, because the cookie could be stolen. This is how sessions work: cookie stores a random ID, random ID is associated with a server-side database.

Comment: I was planning to store the guid token in the same table as the username and password and do a lookup on both username and token, if they match (user is authenticated) and I would generate a new token and update the cookie and token fields in the database, so it would be a one use token.